# How to extend sealed class by decorator design pattern?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

Decorator pattern Usage:

Anybody can show the example how to extend sealed class functionality by Decor patter.

Comment: Do your sealed class implement some interface, or have some base class? It would be nice to see class definition here

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to inherit from [sealed class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/88c54tsw.aspx) in .NET. So, if you want to create decorator which inherits your sealed class, then answer is - it is not possible.

```
public class Decorator : SealedClass // not possible
```

If your sealed class implements some interface or inherits some base class, then you can create decorator which inherits same class/interface. Decorator will not look like your class to clients, but you will be able to use it to decorate your class.

```
public sealed class SealedClass : InterfaceA

public class Decorator : InterfaceA
```

Another option - create some new interface (it can look exactly like your sealed class interface) and implement decorator for this interface. Then create sealed class Adapter for this interface. Clients will use your new interface. You will be able to decorate adapter

```
public class Decorator : InterfaceB // same members as SealedClass have

public class Adapter : InterfaceB
{
    private SealedClass adaptee;

    public Adapter(SealedClasss adaptee)
    {
       this.adaptee = adaptee;
    }

    public int Member1()
    {
        return adaptee.Member1();
    }

    // etc for each member of SealedClass
}
```